# AbandonedMutexException while releasing in finally block

Tags: c#, mutex

I have an application that stores large lists in cache. To prevent several users to fill this cache at the same time, I am using a Mutex. However, I get occasional errors:

> System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException: The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex.

You would argue that I forgot to release the Mutex but the release is in a Finally block so it should always release it. How can the code below cause a AbandonedMutexException? The 'mutex.ReleaseMutex' is supposed to be fired always.

```
    public static List<Objects.SearchListItem> GetActiveCwPropertyListItemsByCwPropertyAndCulture(CwProperty cwProperty, string cultureCode)
{
    var cacheKey = "GetActiveCwPropertyListItemsByCwPropertyAndCulture_" + cwProperty.Guid + "_" + cultureCode;
    var mutex = new Mutex(true, cacheKey);
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        var cachedValue = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        if (cachedValue != null) return (List<Objects.SearchListItem>)cachedValue;
        var value = new List<Objects.SearchListItem>();
        var dr = new CwDbAccess(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CwPropertyListItemPart_LoadByCwProperty");
        try
        {
            dr.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.MyReader.Read())
            {
                value.Add(new Objects.SearchListItem
                {
                    Name = Utils.ProperCase(dr.MyReader["Name"].ToString()),
                    Key = dr.MyReader["CwPropertyListItem_Guid"].ToString(),
                    IsAlias = false
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CwLogging.LogException("Caching.ListItems.GetActiveCwPropertyListItemsByCwPropertyAndCulture", ex, ExceptionLevel.Urgent);
        }
        finally
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
        var keys = new List<string>();
        AddDependency("CwSiteClusterKey_" + cwProperty.CachedCwEntity.CwSiteClusterGuid, keys);
        AddDependency("CwPropertyKey_" + cwProperty.Guid, keys);
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, value, new CacheDependency(null, keys.ToArray()), Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        return value;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

The full stacktrace is:

> System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException: The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex.
>      at System.Threading.WaitHandle.ThrowAbandonedMutexException()
>      at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>      at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
>      at Common.Caching.ListItems.GetActiveCwPropertyListItemsByCwPropertyAndCulture(CwProperty cwProperty, String cultureCode)
>      at Model.SearchFacet.GetAllSearchListItems(CwContext cwContext)
>      at Common.Search.SqlFacets.RetrieveSqlFacetsByGroup(CwEntity cwEntity, NameValueCollection storedRequestForm, SqlFacetsContainer sqlFacets, SearchFacetGroupCollection groups, SearchTemplate searchTemplate, CwContext cwContext)
>      at Common.Search.SqlFacets.RetrieveSqlFacets(CwEntity cwEntity, NameValueCollection storedRequestForm, CwContext cwContext, SearchResultViewType searchResultViewType)
>      at Common.Caching.SqlFacets.GetSqlFacets(String hash, NameValueCollection storedRequestForm, CwEntity cwEntity, CwContext cwContext, SearchResultViewType searchResultViewType)
>      at Compareware_WebApp.Ui.Pages.SearchPage.AppendSearchAndResults(StringBuilder sb) in C:\Projects\Compareware\Compareware.WebApp\Ui\Pages\SearchPage.cs:line 454
>      at Compareware_WebApp.Ui.Pages.SearchPage.get_MainContent() in C:\Projects\Compareware\Compareware.WebApp\Ui\Pages\SearchPage.cs:line 310
>      at ASP.default_aspx.__RenderContent2(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at ASP.masters_site_master.__RenderForm1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at ASP.masters_site_master.__RenderBody(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at ASP.masters_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Going to need a MCVE. There isn't enough information to debug this. Something, somewhere must not be releasing the mutex.

Comment: Your mutex should be static really. I don't think you should create a Mutex on every call, it also smells wrong to then flag the mutex ownership to `true` everytime. What if two threads create two mutexes at the same time, who's the owner? These are just vague observations TBF

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: John, I added the stacktrace.

Comment: @Liam Should I use Mutex.OpenExitsing then?

Comment: From what I can see, as @Liam said there is no reason for you to be creating a new mutex every time you call this function. What you are trying to protect is the cache and there isn't multiple instances of this cache. You should instead use a single mutex instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a single mutex instead of declaring a new mutex for every function call. Perhaps declare a static mutex in the scope of the class this function is in, and wait/release as needed. Check the example on this page :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2